# Finding a element version in ClearCase that exists in only certain versions of its parent directory

Tags: find, clearcase, cleartool

Here is the situation.

Let's say I have a file, "foo.cpp".
Its parent directory is /path/to/foo/ .

- /vobs/myvob/path/to/foo@@/main/release/1  **DOES NOT** contain foo.cpp
- /vobs/myvob/path/to/foo@@/main/release/2  **DOES** contain foo.cpp
- /vobs/myvob/path/to/foo@@/main/release/3  **DOES NOT** contain foo.cpp

So, foo.cpp exists only in:

```
/vobs/myvob/path/to/foo@@/main/release/2/foo.cpp@@/main/release/some-branch/{versions}
```

where *{versions}* are several versions of foo.cpp e.g. 1, 2, 3, LATEST.

My config spec is very generic, as my script needs to parse over hundreds of different branches in order to find certain versions of the files:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/release/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
```

So clearly,

```
ct find . -name 'foo.cpp' -print
```

will not find foo.cpp on branch "some-branch".

I tried:

```
ct find . -a -nvi -name 'foo.cpp' -branch 'brtype(some-branch)' -print
ct find . -a -nvi -name 'foo.cpp' -print | grep some-branch
ct find . -a -nvi -name '*' | grep foo.cpp
```

None of these found foo.cpp.

Any ideas?  Could my config spec be modified in any way to make this easier?

Answer (score 1):

From "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)":

> The `cleartool find` command is used to locate ClearCase objects within a VOB, and **is not restricted by the view's configuration specification (config spec)**.

Make sure to use a dynamic view.

```
ct find . -a -nvis -name 'foo.cpp' -ver 'brtype(some-branch)' -print
# or:
ct find . -nvis -name 'foo.cpp' -ver 'brtype(some-branch)' -print
```

The option `-ver` is mandatory in order to find and list versions.

Comment: Hmm, I did not try -ver.  I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: @livefree75 sure: what "did not work", what error message did you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that the file is in /vobs/myvob/path/to/foo@@/main/release/2, you could modify your config spec to have

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element /vobs/myvob/path/to/foo /main/release/2
element * /main/release/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
```

Then, perform your search as described above. You will then not need -nvi option as you will be in a view that can see the object.

Taking into account you want a generic answer, I would then suggest the usage of the following command

```
 cleartool find -all -name "foo.cpp" -version 'brtype(some-branch)' -print
```

Don't use -nvi option unless you want to list only the versions that are not visible in your view.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a generic solution that will work for any path.

Comment: @livrefree75: I edited the answer to take into account your comment.